# Multiply two columns and sum them on inner join

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I need to get the sum of `a.TOTAL * b.QUANTITY`.

`a` (`A_ID`, `TOTAL`)

`b` (`B_ID`,  `QUANTITY`)

So far I wrote:

```
SELECT a.A_ID, a.TOTAL * b.QUANTITY as calculation
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON 
a.A_ID = b.B_ID
```

I tried `...SUM(a.TOTAL * b.QUANTITY)` as calculation but it doesn't work. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results to explain why your calculation doesn't work.

Comment: And you should also tell us which version of SQL you are using.  I think using `SUM` without `GROUP BY` isn't even allowed for certain databases (MySQL being one exception).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT A_ID, SUM(calculation) as mySum
FROM (
    SELECT a.A_ID, a.TOTAL * b.QUANTITY as calculation
    FROM a INNER JOIN b ON 
    a.A_ID = b.B_ID
) q
GROUP BY A_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you intend to do a grouping on A's id.  If so, then this might give your desired result:

```
SELECT a.A_ID,
       SUM(a.TOTAL * b.QUANTITY) AS calculation
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.A_ID = b.B_ID
GROUP BY a.A_ID
```